Swiftui TabView - TabView without button - keeping the Tab Bar always visible
In my app I have a tab bar that can access various pages.  I would like to add a "Home" view that is accessed from outside the tab bar, for example from the top Navigation Bar.  This view should look and work exactly like all the other pages in the app, with the tab bar visible and with the blur overlay of the scroll content.
As the page is not accessed from the Tab Bar, there should be no button on the Tab Bar.
The only way I can see to achieve this in other answers (e.g. Creating View inside TabView without showing its icon on tab bar) is to create a ZStack - but this hides the Tab Bar and therefore removes access to the other pages.

The ZStack approach should work, try adding padding to the bottom of your home view to allow the tab bar to show through from behind.

I did try that, but the previously active page remains selected (blue), and it's content is visible (blurred) behind the tab bar, not the content of the home page

A custom tab bar would give you more options. You could show it as the top layer of the ZStack and change its appearance to "nothing selected" when the home view is showing. See this answer for an example.

Thanks I'll have a look at that!
